# retention_policy terraform is deprecated inside azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting how to update it using azurerm_storage_management_policy

Tags: azure, terraform

`retention_policy` has been deprecated in favor of `azurerm_storage_management_policy` resource - to learn more https://aka.ms/diagnostic_settings_log_retention

do you know and have some examples how to implement it using the azurerm_storage_management_policy resource?

so how to implement this block using:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
  name                       = "example"
  target_resource_id         = azurerm_linux_web_app.example.id

  log {
    category = "AppServiceHTTPLogs"
    enabled  = true

    retention_policy {
      enabled = true
      days    = 10
    }
  }
```

did not try with azure `azurerm_storage_management_policy` since from documentation it is not clear how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, set up azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting without retention_policy:

```
    resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  //other config
  log {
    category = "AppServiceHTTPLogs"
    enabled  = true
  }
  //other config
}
```

Then, define the retention using azurerm_storage_management_policy:

```
   resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "example" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  rule {
    name    = "appservice-logs-retention"
    enabled = true
    filters {
      prefix_match = ["log-files/AppServiceHTTPLogs"]
      blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
    }
    actions {
      base_blob {
        delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: and we save these logs in resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
how then i can delete from storage account since we have log in log_analytics?

Comment: if i understand correctly your question check log_analytics_workspace reource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_workspace.html you should find property retention_in_days

Comment: in order to use retention_days on log level not on whole level of log_anlytics since retenrtion days are different per logs type

Comment: is it possible to do it then without creating a new storage account(blobs) for logs just to activate retetntion_days? So we need additional resource now?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/storage_management_policy So this means now that we need to create a storage account in additionally to log workspaces where we save logs in order to just set retention for this logs inside diagnostic setting :o ???

Comment: For logs sent to a Log Analytics workspace, retention is set for each table on the Tables page of your workspace. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/migrate-to-azure-storage-lifecycle-policy?tabs=portal

Comment: but again this is not solving an issue that we want to set retention for logs for the specific app not for the whole AppServiceHTTPLogs(30 days default) table so from this removal of retention days from diagnostic settings this possibility is gone :(

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to update retention_policy terraform which is deprecated inside azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting and I able to provision the requirement using **`azurerm_storage_management_policy`**

The `retention_policy` block inside the `azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting` resource is no longer supported. You need to use the `azurerm_storage_management_policy` resource to manage how long logs are kept in Azure.

You can use `azurerm_storage_management_policy` to set up log retention. First, create a storage account where you will store the logs as blobs. Then, define a storage management policy for the blobs and specify the retention period for the logs.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
# Define the provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-ws"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

# Create a storage account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "vksbstacc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

# Create a blob container in the storage account
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "logs"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "blob"
}

# Create a storage management policy to define log retention
resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "example" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  rule {
    name    = "retention-policy"
    enabled = true
    filters {
      prefix_match = ["logs/"]
      blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
    }
    actions {
      base_blob {
        tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than    = 3
        tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 9
        delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than          = 10
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "demovkb"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

# Create a Linux Web App
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example" {
  name                = "vksbdemo-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
   
   site_config {}
}



# Create a diagnostic setting for the Linux Web App
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  name                       = "vksb-setting"
  target_resource_id         = azurerm_linux_web_app.example.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id

  enabled_log {
    category = "AppServiceHTTPLogs"
  }

    metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
  }

  # Send logs to the storage account
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]